# Step-By-Step Process of Solving for (y).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for (y):

> $$a - \frac{B\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}{1+Bn\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}y = 0$$

(Y) and (y) are different variables. I would like a simplified answer to this, because I came across two possible answers to this problem:

> $$y=\frac{ad}{B(d-nY)}$$

and

> $$y=\frac{ad}Y$$

Which one is it?

What is the step-by-step process?

Comment: The uppercase and lowercase $y$s are different variables?

Comment: Yes. (Y) and (y) are different variables.

Answer (score 0):

If the uppercase and lowercase $y$s are different variables, you can proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
& a - \frac{B\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}{1+Bn\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}y = 0
\tag*{$+\frac{B\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}{1+Bn\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}y$}\\
\iff & a =\frac{B\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}{1+Bn\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}y
\tag*{$\cdot \left(1+Bn\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}\right)$}\\
\iff & \left(1+Bn\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}\right) \cdot a = \left( B\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)} \right) y \\
\iff & \frac{1+Bn\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}}{B\frac{Y}{B(d-Yn)}} \cdot a = y.
\end{align}